# How to remove item from NewList in Pharo 5

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I've tried to remove an item from a NewList but there is no method for this. It is safe to access the list items directly? Why there is no removeItem: method?

```
| m |
m := NewListModel new.
m items: (1 to: 50) asOrderedCollection.
m headerTitle: 'Fubu'.
m setSelectedIndex: 2.
m listItems remove: 3.
m openWithSpec.
```

The above works but if I have domain objects it will fail with message:

```
ShouldNotImplement: #remove:ifAbsent: should not have been implemented in Array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `remove:` an item from `m listItems` as shown in your next to last statement above. Send the `m items:` message again instead. For the argument of this message let your model object provide the collection of items that no longer contains the element you want removed.

Of course if those elements are held in an `Array` you will not be able to `remove:` anything from it, and will need to provide a new `Array` as a copy of the original without the removed element. However, if your model keeps the elements in an `OrderedCollection`, it would just be a matter of removing the element from it.

In other words, you need an *actual* model object in charge of knowing which elements belong in the collection and the `NewModelList` instance reflecting this situation rather than the `NewModelList` holding and maintaining such a collection by removing or adding elements to it because that's the job of your *actual* model object. Both objects will point to the very same collection but with different responsibilities on it.